# Why does a JavaScript function fail with certain parameter names?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following JavaScript function is supposed to make a simple JQuery call to load a page and set a class:

```
function Lp(page,class) {
    $("#result").load(page);
    $('#nav').attr('class',class);
}
```

However it failed to work until, on a hunch, I changed the name of the second parameter:

```
function Lp(page,hilite) {
    $("#result").load(page);
    $('#nav').attr('class',hilite);
}
```

Surely the parameter names are arbitrary, or am I missing something?

Comment: Doesn't your error console tell you what's wrong with that?

Answer (score 5):

`class` is a [reserved keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) in JavaScript. That's why.